# Error when trying to include <QSettings> in MFC application

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

When i try to

```
#include <QSettings>
```

in my MFC app I get the following errors

> Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qobject.h': No such file or directory

I want to use the `QSetting` for my MFC application, so how should I code it to resolve the error and allow me to use the `QSettings`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you on visual studio, add %QTDIR%/include to your include path. %QTDIR% is the root directory for qt installation, for example "C:\Qt\4.7.3"

Comment: any idea why i include the qt installation directory "C:\Qt\4.7.3" but the subfolders in it are not auto included too somehow, is there some settings i need to set in vs such that when i include a path, the subfolders in it are alo included? thanks!

Comment: The subdirectories are usually adressed by adding the subfolder, e.g. #include <QtCore/qobject.h>

Comment: subfolders are not included. The behaviour is such as this - if you write `#include <xxx>` , compiler will look all dirs in include list from up to down, and will stop looking if find matching name (<one of include dirs>\xxx) in our case. So if you want to find `#include <QtCore/qobject.h>` , and path to that file is `C:\QT\4.7.3\include\qtCore\qobject.h` - you should add all before `QtCore/qobject.h` to your project include dirs, i.e. `C:\QT\4.7.3\include\`

Comment: And as Raiv observes, the include should look like this:
$(QTDIR)\include
I always have an environment variable QTDIR set to C:\QT\4.7.3 so that I can switch all my projects from one QT version to a newer one without changing the project settings.